# MySQL insert query where a value does not match

Tags: mysql

I would like to insert some data into mySQL like this:

```
INSERT INTO user_data (user_id,value) VALUES (1,2)
```

Is there a way to make sure the same value for the user doesn't exist? I want it to only insert the data if value for user_id does not already exist?

So basically a user_id can have multiple values. I know this can be done unique field. But I am looking to do this with a SQL query

Comment: Make the unique primary key over both columns.

Comment: You don't want to do this in a SQL Query you can get race conditions.. Making a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE KEY on user_id, value is the best solution

Comment: I understand that this can be done with UNIQUE value, but as explained in my original post, I need this particular insert to be done with a SQL query because i am using it to back-date data and the table field does allow for non-unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like others have pointed out in the comments, it would be easier/better if you could add UNIQUE key to the table and then you could simply use `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

But since you said that is not an option this could also work

```
INSERT INTO user_data (user_id, value)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 1, 2) AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT user_id FROM user_data WHERE user_id = 1 AND value = 2
) LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `NOT EXISTS` in combination with the `INSERT` statement.

```
INSERT INTO user_data (`user_id`, `value`) 
SELECT DISTINCT 1,2 
FROM `user_data`
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM `user_data` 
    WHERE `user_id` = 1 AND `value` = 2
);
```

This makes sure it only inserts when it does not already exist.